# In windows server 2008, how do I disable recursive dns and continue to navigate the internet?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, bind, internet, dns-hosting

I have a single win2008 server configured to use vpn and remote desktop.  My host provider demanded I remove recursive DNS.

If go to dns role / group / properties / advanced and click disable recursive, after that I lose internet access. I can't navigate.

I changed to Bind but had the same problem.

In this server I need access to internet for some web services, so I can't just leave it like this.  How do I keep recursive DNS off and still retain the ability to navigate the internet?

Comment: Make the DNS server not publicly accessible from the Internet by making it listen only on internal addresses.  See: [Restrict a DNS server to listen only on selected addresses](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc755068.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Why are you running the DNS Server role on this server?

Comment: joeqwerty in the first time I turn  on to configurate the remote connections, and a internal lan, but i try to erase the role and i obtain the same problem, internet not works

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure [forwarders](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff807391%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).  To quote from the linked article:

> - Click Start, click Run, type dnsmgmt.msc, and then press ENTER. The DNS Manager console will open.
> - In the console tree, click the name of the DNS server you wish to configure.
> - On the Action menu, click Properties.
> - Click the Forwarders tab.
> - Modify the list of forwarders as follows:
>
>   - To add a forwarder to the list, click Edit, specify the name and IP address of the server to be added to the list, and then click OK.
>   - To modify a forwarder in the list, click Edit, click the forwarder you wish to configure, modify the name or IP address of the forwarder,
>       and then click OK.
>   - To remove a forwarder from the list, click Edit, click the forwarder you wish to remove, clear the IP address field, and then
>       click OK.

You also need to block access to DNS on your server from outside your internal domain.

> [Note:](https://support.appliedi.net/kb/a1010/how-to-disable-recursion-on-a-windows-dns-server.aspx) If your server has a legitimate need to perform DNS recursion
>   (example - you have applications that need to resolve external DNS),
>   you can alternately disable and/or scope the local Windows Firewall
>   rule that allows incoming DNS requests.

I don't know what, if anything, else is on your network, but you can:

- [Use Windows firewall to block all but specific IP addresses.](https://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/preventing-dns-amplification-attacks-via-the-windows-firewall-in-windows-2008-r2-or-windows)

[image]

- Tell your DNS server which IP addresses to answer DNS queries on.  This is in server properties, like the information above, but on the Interfaces tab.

[image]

- Block DNS at an external firewall.

Answer (score 1):

By default the DNS server listens on all interfaces / IP addresses. Most DNS servers set to allow recursive queries should not be listening on a public interface / IP address. Doing so allows them to be used in a DNS applification attack (a type of DDOS), ref: US-Cert [DNS Amplification Attacks](https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/TA13-088A).

Configure the DNS server to only listen on internal addresses.

```
dnscmd <ServerName> /ResetListenAddresses [<ListenAddress> ...]
```

For help:

```
dnscmd <ServerName> /ResetListenAddresses /help
```

TechNet: [Restrict a DNS server to listen only on selected addresses](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc755068.aspx)